# Converting a JR-Rail Pass?

Tags: trains, japan, japan-rail, jr-passes

When you convert JR-Rail pass voucher to a JR-Rail pass, can you set the date or does it start from that moment?

When I have a start date for the Japan Rail pass, can I start to make reservations?

For example, arriving in Japan on the 1st, wanting to start travel on the 8th and start reserving the seats before that time. Is it possible?

I'd rather not waste time on the day of travel getting the pass and we won't be near  a major JR rail pass exchange station that day.

Comment: You have already answered your own question, but I wanted to quickly comment saying that on my recent trip to Japan, we didn't bother reserving seats on any of our train journeys. We had no problems finding seats in unreserved coaches and never had anyone sitting next to us. Often the reserved coaches were busier and people had to share rows of seats with others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out that I can set the date when I exchange. More info here: http://www.japan-rail-pass.com/common-questions/can-i-choose-the-days-of-use